# Force to render images in mails

Tags: email, drupal-7, html-email

I created a newsletter with `simplenews` module and `mime mail` module in D7 and all the things like sending email and subscribing work correctly , but there is something i'd like to ask :

How can i render images in email ????
Now images are hidden in email and you have to click on ***"This message contains blocked image. Show images . "***

Is there any trick that show images in email without any clicks ?

And

Why Yahoo-mail show mails in inbox and gmail show them in spam ?

Comment: This is possiple if you use attached images instead of external images. But I don't know if the `simplenews` module.

Answer (score 0):

What you asking for cannot be done by the sender. This is an anti-spam feature of the email client and by default, it will block images from unknown senders. Your message is appearing in the spam folder may be due to these and other reasons:

1. "Spammy" content
2. High image to text ratio
3. You've been flagged as spam before

There are many other factors that goes into deliverability, such as server reputation, user preference, user interaction and so on. Spam filters exist to keep unwanted emails away from users.

The only sure way to make sure you land in the inbox and have your images shown by default, is to get added to the recipient's address book (getting whitelisted) and have them turn their images on by default.

If you would like further reading or to perform spam testing before you send emails, check out [Litmus](http://www.litmus.com). They're great.